# jdk-5 error while building android source code

Tags: android, jvm, android-emulator, java-5

i am trying to build linux kernel for android emulator(Eclair version).
i have downloaded the android source code, and also "$repo sync" was successful. 
now for Building, when i try to execute "$make" command i get the following error.

## root@ubuntu:~/mydroid# make

PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=2.1-update1
TARGET_PRODUCT=generic
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_SIMULATOR=
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release

## BUILD_ID=ECLAIR

Checking build tools versions...

---

You are attempting to build with the incorrect version
of java.

Your version is: /bin/bash: java: command not found.
The correct version is: 1.5.

Please follow the machine setup instructions at
    http://source.android.com/download

---

build/core/main.mk:111: *** stop.  Stop.

i had open-jdk6 and sun-jdk-6 installed, now for building android source, it needs sun-jdk-1.5. 
for this i tried to install sun-jdk-1.5 from the .bin file, but the default JVM is not initialised to jdk-1.5, and i am not able to do it.
i uninstalled open-jdk-6 but i couldnt remove sun-jdk-6.  i have installed sun-jdk-6 from a .bin file from oracle/downloads.

i am following steps from below link

http://linuxclues.blogspot.com/2010/04/building-android-debian-sid.html

please tell me how can i uninstall jdk-6 and set the default jvm path to sun-jdk-5.
or is there any other way to set the default jvm.. please help.

Comment: It looks like it just can't find the java executable. You might just need to add it to your path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set JDK 1.5 in your PATH variable before JDK 1.6. So the system will pick 1.5 instead of 1.6

Comment: i got the answer. its here   http://zebardast.ir/en/installing-sun-jdk-5-on-ubuntu-9-10-and-10-04/                                    thank you!